# Diagonalizable Operators: An Operational Extension

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, operator-theory

Let $T$ be a diagonalizable operator on a vector space $V$. Prove that the operator
$$a_nT^n + a_{n-1}T^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1T+a_0 Id_V$$
 on $V$ is also diagonalizable for any scalars $a_1, a_1,\dots,a_n$.

---

First off, what is $Id_V$? I've never seen this before.

Comment: $Id_V$ is the identity operator on $V$, i.e. the map that sends any $v\in V$ to itself.

Comment: is $T$ a linear operator? Since i see the tag "linear-algebra" this question came to my mind. If so then $T$ can be rappresented by a diag. matrix. Then we can use the fact that powers of diag. matrices are diag. and linear combinations of diag. matrices are diag.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\exists\,P\;\,\text{an invertible operator}\,\;s.t.\;\, P^{-1}TP=D\;\,\text{is diagonal}\implies \forall\,n\in\Bbb N:$$

$$P^{-1}T^nP=\left(P^{-1}TP\right)^n=D^n\;\;\text{is diagonal,  and from here the claim follows}$$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose $V$ is $d$-dimensional and $T$ is represented by a square matrix. Then $T$ diagonalizable if it is similar to a diagonal matrix $D=\mathop{\rm diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d)$, i.e., there is an invertible matrix $S$ such that $D=S^{-1}TS$. Now 
\begin{equation}
S^{-1}T^nS=S^{-1}TS\cdot S^{-1}TS\cdots S^{-1}TS=D^n,
\end{equation}
and since $D^n=\mathop{\rm diag}(\lambda_1^n,\ldots,\lambda_d^n)$ is again diagonal, it follows that $T^n$ is diagonal for any $n$. Hence, by linearity, your operator is diagonal.

If $T$ is considered as an endomorphism on an abstract $d$-dimensional vector space it is called diagonalizable if there is a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_d\}$ of eigenvectors (notice that then the matrix of $T$ wrt. $\{v_1,\ldots,v_d\}$ will be diagonal, and the matrix of $T$ wrt. any other basis is diagonalizable in the above sense). Now if $T(v_i)=\lambda_iv_i$ we get $T^n(v_i)=\lambda_i^nv_i$, $i=1,\ldots,d$, thus $\{v_1,\ldots,v_d\}$ is a basis of eigenvectors of $T^n$, and we conclude.

Answer (score -1):

I found this in Michael Artin's *Algebra*, and I feel it will be of use here:

[image]

Comment: -1? Why? Why? Why?

Comment: @DonAntonio How do you explain equality $3$ in (4.6.14)?  $$f(A)\overset{1}{=}f(P\Lambda P^{-1})\overset{2}{=}a_0Id_V+a_1P\Lambda P^{-1}+\cdots+a_nP\Lambda P^{-1}\overset{3}{=}Pf(\Lambda)P^{-1}$$

Comment: Oh, it's just distributivity.